# problem with injecting abstract class in spring

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I have two abstract classes

```
class abstract A {
//some methods .
}

class abstract B extends A {
 private  C  c ;
//other methods
}
```

Spring config file :

```
<bean id="b" class="B" abstract="true">
    <property name="c" ref="C" />   //I have reference for C else where
</bean>
```

When I run the program , the class c is not getting injected . It is coming as null . Am i missing something ?

Comment: how do you create instance of B ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`abstract=true` means that the bean specification is a 'template' for other bean declarations to extend, it does not mean the class is abstract.  I suspect bean with id `b` is not being created since it is a template/abstract definition.  Remove `abstract=true` and make `B` a concrete type and it should work.

Documentation here: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions

Answer (score 0):

You don't show a setter for C in the abstract class B.  You must use either setting or constructor injection.  The code as posted can't work.

You should also specify B as the parent bean for C; likewise A for B.

Comment: C has setters . I am using setter injection.

Answer (score 0):

Although the use of 'abstract="true"' is not meant to indicate that the bean specification is for an abstract class, it is still required for an abstract class bean definition so that pre-instantiation is not attempted on that class (which would fail for an abstract class). This is indicated in a note below the section that the above link points to (http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-child-bean-definitions). If this were a situation where the super class was not an abstract class, then yes, 'abstract="true"' should not be used.